# How to add Auto complete feature in Angular drop down list?

Tags: angular, rest, filter, autocomplete, dropdown

I'm trying to add an auto complete featrue for the drop down list in Angular by following a tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxaSPGDXAqo&t=190s
But i'm getting an error as I'm getting the values from an object.

````
 ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions=this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value))
    );
  }
private filter(value:string):templateData[]{
const filterValue=value.toLowerCase();
return this.DROPDOWN_LIST.filter(option=>option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue);
}

``` i'm loading the values froma  rest API and adding it to DROPDOWN_LIST variable which is of type templateData
````

Answer (score 1):

Refer this link. First example.

https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples 
After copying code or refering example include

```
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
```

in app.module.ts